# Put NIC under heavy load

Tags: hardware, nic, server-crashes, stress-testing

I think I've got a faulty NIC so I want to put it under heavy but controlled load to see if and when it dies.

How can I generate such a load?

The NIC is in a Hyper-V host with Windows and Linux guests running on it so tools or methods for either platform are fine.

Comment: Iperf (https://iperf.fr/) is a nice tool to push network connections to their limit..

Answer (score 5):

You should examine/post any errors you've received... Why do you suspect you have a problem? What behaviors have you seen on the system. And you should definitely have multiple NICs available for hypervisor VM traffic to counter this issue.

If you suspect the NIC is bad, and it's a standalone device, replace it. If it's on a system board/motherboard, check hardware alerts. Is this a server-class system? Is there a warranty or support contract?

Iperf is a fine load generator, but a failing NICs behavior is not necessarily a function of the amount of traffic flowing through it.